# separate lines according to a string in them in python

Tags: python, startswith

I have a [file](https://btude-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/carsten_wedemeyer_b-tu_de/EZtvxQSS0F1Hi50VGqdmvpMBDQNuOYUiMBC6htJ5ARdFeg?e=i1vr35) containing (~1000) lines of data in the following -simplified- form:

```
movej(p[-0.2875, -0.4, 0.05, -0.0004, 3.1415, 0.0002],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.000000) 
movej([-1.3615, -2.0244, -1.5691, -2.6895, 0.2092, 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)
movel(p[-0.2875, -0.375, 0.0, -0.0004, 3.1415, 0.0002],a=0.500000,v=0.300000,r=0.000000)
movel([-1.2437, -1.9458, -2.0485, -2.2887, 0.0128, 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)
# Various comments
## Various comments
### Various comments
```

And I need to separate the lines in two sets (for later conversion to pandas dataframes), one set consisting of the lines with the p -starting with "movej(p[" or "movel(p[" and the other consisting of the lines without the p -starting with "movej([" or "movel([".

```
movej(p[-0.2875, -0.4, 0.05, -0.0004, 3.1415, 0.0002],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.000000) 
movel(p[-0.2875, -0.375, 0.0, -0.0004, 3.1415, 0.0002],a=0.500000,v=0.300000,r=0.000000)

and

movej([-1.3615, -2.0244, -1.5691, -2.6895, 0.2092, 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)
movel([-1.2437, -1.9458, -2.0485, -2.2887, 0.0128, 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)
```

To do so, I have created the following code that almost does the job.

The issue I am experiencing is that it stops or doesn't store everything in the TCP_lines and joint_lines strings.
I have also tried using list with the same result.

```
with open("SRP_Assemble all BUSH_BEARING onto HPC_FRONT_BOTTOM.script", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    TCP_lines = ""
    joint_lines = ""

    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(("movej(p" ,"movel(p")):
            TCP_lines += line
        elif line.startswith(("movej(" ,"movel(")):
            joint_lines += line

print (TCP_lines)
print (joint_lines)
```

EDIT:
Does the console have a limited space to print results?
So it only prints the first couple of rows?

I used a redirector to print the results in a text box and it looks fine...

Comment: Do you have an example of line that is missing in your output?

Answer (score 0):

Move the print statements inside the context manager and add a debugging line, Like so:

```
with open("SRP_Assemble all BUSH_BEARING onto HPC_FRONT_BOTTOM.script", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    TCP_lines = ""
    joint_lines = ""

    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(("movej(p", "movel(p")):
            TCP_lines += line
        elif line.startswith(("movej(", "movel(")):
            joint_lines += line
        else:
            print(line)  # Check all other lines if they failed to pass the check
    print(TCP_lines)
    print(joint_lines)
```

This outputs:

```
movej(p[-0.2875, -0.4, 0.05, -0.0004, 3.1415, 0.0002],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.000000)
movel(p[-0.2875, -0.375, 0.0, -0.0004, 3.1415, 0.0002],a=0.500000,v=0.300000,r=0.000000)

movej([-1.3615, -2.0244, -1.5691, -2.6895, 0.2092, 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)
movel([-1.2437, -1.9458, -2.0485, -2.2887, 0.0128, 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate what you are doing. The below outputs the correct lines. What output do you get?

```
lines = ["movej(p[-0.2875, -0.4, 0.05, -0.0004, 3.1415, 0.0002],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.000000)",
"movej([-1.3615, -2.0244, -1.5691, -2.6895, 0.2092, 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)",
"movel(p[-0.2875, -0.375, 0.0, -0.0004, 3.1415, 0.0002],a=0.500000,v=0.300000,r=0.000000)",
"movel([-1.2437, -1.9458, -2.0485, -2.2887, 0.0128, 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)",]

TCP_lines = ""
joint_lines = ""

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(("movej(p" ,"movel(p")):
        TCP_lines += line
    elif line.startswith(("movej(" ,"movel(")):
        joint_lines += line

print (TCP_lines)
print (joint_lines)
```

**OUT**:

> movej(p[-0.2875, -0.4, 0.05, -0.0004, 3.1415,
> 0.0002],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.000000)movel(p[-0.2875, -0.375, 0.0, -0.0004, 3.1415, 0.0002],a=0.500000,v=0.300000,r=0.000000)
>
> movej([-1.3615, -2.0244, -1.5691, -2.6895, 0.2092,
> 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)movel([-1.2437, -1.9458, -2.0485, -2.2887, 0.0128, 1.2197],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)

Comment: These are the last lines I am getting on joint_lines
movej([-1.3887151912257936, 3.809970261372717, -2.250286407217747, 1.5819087994348224, 0.4462373951488581, -1.9218494254572147],a=5.000000,v=5.000000,r=0.050000)
movej([-1.5995894633995478, 3.5770074439575943, -2.

And these the last on TCP_lines
movel(p[-0.23750000000000002, -0.4, 0.05, -0.0004363323129985824, 3.1415402937122336, 0.0002617993877991494],a=0.500000,v=0.300000,r=0.000000)
movej(

But if you check the file, these are not the last entries.